# UIBarButtonItem created using Storyboard isn't triggering, with no errors in the logs

Tags: ios, swift

When I create two `UIBarButtonItem's` on a `UINavigationItem` in `Storyboard` in Swift 5, using XCode 10.2.1, the `buttons` get enabled correctly and can be clicked, but the `IBAction` associated never gets triggered when I click on them.

I have two `IBAction` methods called `saveButtonPressed` and `cancelButtonPressed`, and also have both the cancel button and save button hooked up with an `Unwind seque` action to another `ViewController`, which has the `unwindToPeriodicalList(sender:)` method. I can set up the connection fine, it shows up when I Ctrl+Drag from the buttons to the Exit button on the overarching VC. I also have the `prepare(for seque:)` method defined in the VC that contains the buttons. Nothing seems wrong until I go to click these buttons and nothing happens. The seque back to the originating VC doesn't happen, nor do the methods saveButtonPressed or cancelButtonPressed methods get called. I've redone these IBAction connections what seems like 100 times, under different circumstances, and nothing seems to work. I've followed tutorial after tutorial and nothing has fixed it. Any ideas?

```swift
@IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        os_log("cancelButtonPressed() called", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        os_log("saveButtonPressed() called", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    }
```

No error messages in the logs, nor the os_log messages that tell me saveButtonPressed or cancelButtonPressed were triggered. Yes, I have the debugger output set to All Output and not just one type.

Comment: Could you push demo project?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can answer questions about it though!